# How to avoid duplicate entries from Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code snippet basically sending data to Firestore. In the form, I've set a field call "regNo" which is unique to different entries, what I'm trying to do is avoid duplicate entries if I could use the regNo as a primary key so as to alert the users on the application if it already exists, Here's the code showing entries from the application:

```js
import Sidebar from './../../components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Navbar from './../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import "./new.scss"
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import DriveFolderUploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DriveFolderUpload';
import { addDoc, collection,doc,getDoc,serverTimestamp, setDoc} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const New = ({ title, btnUpd }) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const findUs = ["Referral Doctor", "Website", "Friends", "Facebook", "Nil"]

  const statusCheck = ["married", "divorced", "single"]

  const titled = ["Mr", "Mrs"]

  const sexes = ["Male", "Female"]

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    regNo: "",
    title: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    sex: "",
    email: "",
    reffBy: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    age: "",
    date: "",
    birth: "",
    status: "",
    state: "",
    occupation: "",
    duration: "",
    finding: "",
  });

  // fetch id from the URL
  

  const {userId}  = useParams();
  let id = userId
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let getUserDoc = async (id) => {
      let docRef = doc(db, "mrisystems/" + id);
      let docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log('getUserDoc() received:', docSnap);
      if (docSnap.exists) {
        let theData = docSnap.data();
        console.log('getUserDoc() setting userInfo:', theData);
        setUserInfo(theData);
      }
    }
  
    if (id) {
      getUserDoc(id);
      console.log("IdUser", id)
    } else {
      console.log('useEffect() -- no ID value');
    }
  }, [id]);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setUserInfo({...userInfo, [name]: value});
  }

  // Adding and Updating Existing Records....
  const handleAdd = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        if(isEmpty(id)){
        await addDoc(collection(db, "mrisystems"), {
          ...userInfo,
          timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });    
        toast.error("User Already Exists");
      } else {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "mrisystems/" + id), {
          ...userInfo,
          timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });    
      }
      navigate("/users")
  }
```

What I tried to do was update the condition to check also if the "regNo" state is null, here's the code snippet:

```js
// Adding and Updating Existing Records....
const handleAdd = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    if(isEmpty(id) && userInfo.regNo===null){
    await addDoc(collection(db, "mrisystems "), {
      ...userInfo,
      timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
    });    
    toast.error("User Already Exists");
  } else {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "mrisystems/" + id), {
      ...userInfo,
      timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
    });    
  }
  navigate("/users")
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm getting duplicates, like if I use a regNo of "94IAD" for a particular users document and I use the same regNo number for another users document, it's meant to give an alert that a regNo already exists in the collection

Comment: So is the regNo of "94IAD", the ID of the document?

Comment: So currently I'm using auto ID, but regNo is a field in the document used to identify a certain information of a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a custom ID that is either the regNo, or some sort of hash that accumulates the essential data.
if you have more than one unique entry, you must make a query from the client and validate it with a cloud function to ensure that it is truly unique.

an alternative is to keep a key/value pair in firestore as a sub collection to track what regNo is linked by checking if it exists via security rules. this would have to done with a batch request.

ultimately, this should be a feature request that should be supported.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why would you run a Cloud Function to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: a query does not guarantee uniqueness for writes, it is entirely possible for the query to be skipped in the right or wrong scenarios, leading to duplicates. for this, a source of truth must implemented to be 100% accurate. Honestly, surprised that security rules doesn't have a isUnique flag for properties

Comment: ideally, if security rules had query support via the index table as it can already read document data.

Answer (score 3):

Firestore doesn't have concept of primary key and unique values like SQL. If it's just a sting value, use it as your `documentId`, which is guaranteed to be unique.

In all other cases, you may want to create a string with unique combination of fields and use that as `documetId` or check the existance of duplicate field by querying firestore database before adding new entry.

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment:

> So currently I'm using auto ID, but `regNo` is a field in the document used to identify certain information of a user.

I understand the ID of the document is autogenerated, and the `regNo` is a field inside the document. In this case, to know if a collection already contains a document where the `regNo` field holds a specific value, then you have to perform a query. In code, it should look like this:

```
const queryByRegNo = await getDocs(
  query(
    collection(db, "mrisystems"),
    where("regNo", "==", "94IAD"),
  )
);
queryByRegNo.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

For a more detailed solution, please check Renaud's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76991782/5246885).

Comment: the issue is ensuring it is unique via security rules

Comment: Hi Alex, this query shall be executed in a Transaction IMHO. However it is not possible, with Client SDKs, to execute a Query within a Transaction.

Comment: Hey Renaud. Yes, it makes more sense.

Comment: I have created a feature request for security rules for this situation, vote/share https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/47184644-security-rules-unique-operator

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the Firebase JS Client SDK (you tag the question with `react`) you have to use another collection where you create a document per `regNo`, with `regNo` being the document ID within this collection.

Then you have two possibilities:

##### 1/ Use a Transaction:

In this Transaction, you check if the document exists in the other collection (let's call it `uniquenessRegNo`) before writing the doc:

```
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

try {
  const regNo = "...";
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    const uniquenessRegNoDocRef = doc(db, "uniquenessRegNo", regNo);
    const uniquenessRegNoDoc = await transaction.get(uniquenessRegNoDocRef);
    if (uniquenessRegNoDoc.exists()) {
      throw "Cannot create two docs with same regNo!";
    }

    // We write to the two collections in an atomic manner
    transaction.set(uniquenessRegNoDocRef, { foo: "bar" });
    const docRef = doc(db, "mrisystems/" + id);
    transaction.set(docRef, { regNo, ... });
  });
  console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
}
```

##### 2/ Use a batched write and specific security rules:

Same philosophy as solution 1: We write to the two collections in an atomic way (with a batched write) but here we do the check for the doc in the `uniquenessRegNo` collection through a security rule.

A batched write will ensure that multiple documents write completes atomically and therefore if a document with ID = regNbr exists in the `uniquenessRegNo` collection the **two** writes will fail.

The security rules shall be as follows:

```
match /mrisystems/{docId} { 
  allow read: if ...;
  allow create : if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/uniquenessRegNo/$(request.resource.data.regNbr));
}   

match /uniquenessRegNo/{docId} { 
  allow read: if ...;
  allow create : if true; (to adapt as necessary)
}
```

and the batched write is as follows:

```js
try {
  const batch = writeBatch(db);

  const regNbo = "...";
  const docId = doc(collection(db, "uniquenessRegNo")).id;

  const testUniqueFieldDocRef = doc(db, "mrisystems", docId);
  batch.set(testUniqueFieldDocRef, { regNo, ... });

  const uniquenessRegNoDocRef = doc(db, "uniquenessRegNo", regNo);
  batch.set(uniquenessRegNoDocRef, { bar: "foo" });


  await batch.commit()
} catch (error) {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(errorMessage)
}
```

---

**HOWEVER**, for both the proposed above approaches, there is the possibility that users in the front end bypass the Transaction or the Batched Write by only writing to the `mrisystems` collection (without checking the `uniquenessRegNo` collection).

So if you want to prevent this possibility you'll need to implement the Transaction in a Callable Cloud Function that you call from the front end.

In the Cloud Function, since you use the Admin SDK it is possible to execute a Query in the Transaction with the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) method (which is not possible with the client SDKs, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention?hl=en&authuser=0)). So you can implement the check with only the `mrisystems` collection.

Finally, in the security rules, you deny all write access to the `mrisystems` collection: The users can only use the Cloud Function to write to the collection. And the Cloud Function can write to it since the Admin SDK bypass all security rules.

Comment: I have created a feature request for security rules for this situation, vote/share https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/47184644-security-rules-unique-operator